# Using the Knockout mapping plugin on objects with children

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Let's say I have this data:

```
var data = {
    name: 'Graham',
    children: [
        { id : 1, name : 'Lisa' }
   ]
}
```

Now I map it, add some properties and map it back:

```
var mappedData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
mappedData.age = 44;
mappedData.children[0].age = 12;
var unmappedData = ko.mapping.toJS(mappedData);
```

In the unmappedData root object, age is not present, but in the child object, it is.
This is because the mapping plugin keeps track of the original properties, but only for the root object.

Is there a way, besides using a custom 'create' mapping for every child collection off the root, to turn on this tracking for child collection objects?

Comment: So you want that on the `unmappedData.children[0].age`  should not be 12? Or you want that `unmappedData.age` should be 44?

Comment: In the unmappedData object I want age to not show up. Both for the root object and the children.

Comment: Then probably your only viable option is to use a custom `create` mapping for every child collection... but you can generate the mapping config with the `ko.mapping.visitModel` method: http://jsfiddle.net/2AR75/

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Thanks! I will give you credits for the answer if you put it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your only viable option is to use a custom `create` function for every child collection...

But you don't need to manually create the mapping you can generate the with the using the `ko.mapping.visitModel` method, something like:

```
var mapping = {};
ko.mapping.visitModel(data, function(item, parent) {
    if (ko.mapping.getType(item) === "array")
    {
        mapping[parent] = { 
            create: function(op) { return ko.mapping.fromJS(op.data); }
        }
    }
});
var mappedData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2AR75/).